# Query the json data type in a Postgre database via dotnet

Tags: c#, json, .net, postgresql, jsonb

There is a column in the database table, which stores records in json format and have the form <{"object": ["v1", "v2", ... "vN"]}>. An empty array of values <{"object": []}>. I'm trying to make a valid jsonb query to dotnet to get records with an empty array, <{"object":[]}>. What mistake am I making? My query now looks like this (pseudo code):

```
var selectForQuery = request.Select(s => $"{indeedColumn}->'{object}' = '[]'::jsonb) ? '{s}'");
```

Comment: `''{object}'` : are the double simple quote `'` normal ?

Comment: Oh... Thanks, this is a mistype, I will edit it